# Restrict values to send in a soap web service

Tags: xml, soap, xml-parsing, xml-validation

I have created a soap web service and a xml validator, I'd like to know if there are any anotation I can use in order to retrict values to send in any field, example:

```
   @XmlType
public class ContactoBean implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6034293066688534650L;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private String emailContacto;
    
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private String telfContacto;
    
    @XmlElement(required = false)
    private String faxContacto;
```

Are there any anotation to use a regex in telephone in order to validate if it is a correct number? or to validate the correction of the email?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you having the code-first approach or the contract-first one (generating your classes based on a WSDL+XSD files) ?

If latter, you could extend your related XSD types with xsd:patterns defining a desired regular expression.

Example:

```
<xsd:element name="elementName">
    <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:pattern value="[^*+]"></xsd:pattern>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
```

XMLBeans should than generate the necessary classes, getters and setters for you.

But if you are creating your Webservice directly via Java Code I assume you need to make use of standard Java methods for regular expressions. I found following description for org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.RegularExpression - maybe it helps:

**A. Standard way**

```
RegularExpression re = new RegularExpression(regex);
if (re.matches(text)) { ... }
```

**B. Capturing groups**

```
RegularExpression re = new RegularExpression(regex);
Match match = new Match();
if (re.matches(text, match)) {
    ... // You can refer captured texts with methods of the Match class.
}
```

**Case-insensitive matching**

```
RegularExpression re = new RegularExpression(regex, "i");
if (re.matches(text) >= 0) { ...}
```

**Options**

```
You can specify options to RegularExpression(regex, options) or setPattern(regex, options). This options parameter consists of the following characters.

"i"
This option indicates case-insensitive matching.
"m"
^ and $ consider the EOL characters within the text.
"s"
. matches any one character.
"u"
Redefines \d \D \w \W \s \S \b \B \< \> as becoming to Unicode.
"w"
By this option, \b \B \< \> are processed with the method of 'Unicode Regular Expression Guidelines' Revision 4. When "w" and "u" are specified at the same time, \b \B \< \> are processed for the "w" option.
","
The parser treats a comma in a character class as a range separator. [a,b] matches a or , or b without this option. [a,b] matches a or b with this option.
"X"
By this option, the engine confoms to XML Schema: Regular Expression. The match() method does not do subsring matching but entire string matching.
```

Source: http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/regex/RegularExpression.html

In my opinion, I would suggest the contract-/WSDL-first approach.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. That the thing, I'm doing code first, and I'd to do it with annotation not coding all the validation, this is an example but the service is large..